# Scrolling an android screen automatically with dynamic addition of widgets

Tags: android

I want to scroll a android screen dynamically by clicking a button. The scrollable content will be added dynamically. The screen shot i have attached. As shown in the screen shot i want to scroll the screen like the "Car details" label should be at the top of the screen.

```
    sv.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                        vehicle_no.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        vehicle_no.requestFocus();
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(vehicle_no, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                });
```

This is the code that i am using to scroll the screen. But it's not solving my problem. Please suggest me a solution for this problem. Thank you.
[Add car details](https://plus.google.com/photos/103427035296459068975/albums/6183827556210850289/6183827562084508402)

Comment: Try to give some delay to your post call, it might be possible that scrollview is getting scroll before view is added to it

Comment: Thank you for your response. But my expectation is first the dynamic part will be added, after that i need to scroll the screen to "Car layout" label(to be at top of screen). In the link Add car details i have mentioned the screen shot.

Comment: That's what I am saying you first add view and then call this sv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                your code
            }
        },500);

Comment: It's working . Thank you. But i have mentioned it as "ScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);". That's why it's going to bottom. But i want a scroll that a particular widget should be at the top of the screen. I have used "sv.scrollTo(0,vehicle_no.getTop())". But it's not working. Can you please give me a solution for this!

Comment: What result you get after calling this sv.scrollTo(0,vehicle_no.getTop())

Comment: It's moving to top of the screen

Comment: So what do you want exactly

Comment: I want to scroll the screen that "Add car details" text view should be at the top of the screen(Up to that text view i want the scroll).

Comment: Your screenshot is not able to access it says you dont have permission

Comment: Now i have added screen shot exactly what i want. You can access that screen shot at "https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/103427035296459068975/albums/6183858977128833489/6183858975615195970?pid=6183858975615195970&oid=103427035296459068975"

Comment: I am not getting any thing from that screen shot why that keyboard is there

Comment: Initially the "- car details" will be at the bottom of the screen like "+ car details". When i click on the one the dynamic part will be added after the "- car details" and i need to scroll the screen to the top up to "-car details" text view. The key board i need to pop up dynamically when that dynamic content is added. That's why it is there.

Answer (score 1):

First add view and then call this

```
sv.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
  { @Override 
    public void run() 
  { your code } },500);
```